# Which cloud service is suited for video sharing app

Tags: android, google-app-engine, video, parse-platform, blob

I am building a video sharing app (now android, soon iOS as well). User would capture videos with their cell phones and then share it with each other. Which cloud service is best suited for such application? Is App Engine well suited for this? Or would Parse work better? As an independent developer, price is very much an issue. I have used App Engine with pictures (bitmaps) on the Blobstore, but never videos. Plus the Blobstore is being discontinued. In any case, taking price and **ease of development** into consideration, what is the best service?

Comment: parse works perfectly, and it's basically free. there's some sort of limit on the video length with parse (check for latest).  it's so simple to do this using parse, that, **i urge you to just do it** (there are tutorials everywhere .. google wenderlich parse posts, etc.  indeed **parse gives you a whole demo project that does exactly this**!) my point is try it using parse to get your feet wet, then look in to alternatvies

Comment: Thanks @JoeBlow. So to be clear, Parse will handle my users posting videos with their mobile devices and will allow users to watch videos as well. Thanks. I will do a google search for the tutorial you mention: unless you have a specific link you can provide. Thank you so very much for your reply.

Comment: "Parse will handle my users posting videos with their mobile devices and will allow users to watch videos as well"  yes.  it is incredibly simple.  you need do nothing other than click to parse.com and you will see they give you, for free, a whole demo project that does exactly that!!!  https://www.parse.com/tutorials  get with AnyPic or AnyWall

Comment: Thank you so much. I am looking at it and will let you know how it goes. Thanks!!!

Comment: @JoeBlow AnyWall does not seem to deal with videos at all. AnyPic on the other hand does deal with pictures (not videos) and it's only available for iOS. So they do not seem like clear cut demos for the OP. Just a thought.

Comment: Hi - with anywall, you trivially **change from still images to videos**. it's a trivial change.

Comment: Maybe it would be a better match to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend going with `Parse`. It has a nice open source Android SDK with a lot of features working out of the box such as [Local Datastore](https://parse.com/tutorials/using-the-local-datastore) (you can easily store objects locally), [Offline support](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/take-your-app-offline-with-parse-local-datastore/), REST (already impl), [Files Caching](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parsefile-caching-now-on-android/) (already impl), etc.

The wall you might hit with `Parse` is that it limits the file sizes to `10MB`. So if you want to upload a file of any kind larget than this limit you would have to upload it somewhere else and keep the `URL` to that file in your `ParseObject`. With this limit in mind you might consider checking out also [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) for storing photos & videos.

Comment: +1 for cloudinary recommendation. I haven't used it. But it seems to be the answer to this kind of problem.